# repl in webpage, best way to go about it?

Tags: python, ipython, zeromq, read-eval-print-loop, jupyter-notebook

OK, so I am experimenting with a simple python repl in a browser. I want to put some python code in a text input, and then hit the 'send' button, then get back the result of evaluating it.

I was using flask, with one route, which called the stdlib `eval` function, and then sends it back. I was also using [zeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) with a simple server/client setup. I feel like I am missing something though...

How is the standard way to go about doing this kind of thing? Projects like [repl.it](http://repl.it/) and [skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/) are doing it but they are compiling to javascript. [Ipython notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) is using zeroMQ, well I don't know the exact way they are doing it, sending some python string with a pub/sub setup and then using `exec` I think....

I was thinking I would like to embed repl's into webpages that support many languages, but I am starting with python first. Maybe someone else is doing this already? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPython notebook webapp discuss with a tornado webserver that act as a bridge with ZMQ to talk to kernels, kernels might be python, julia, haskell, OCamel, nodejs, ruby, scala ... for thoses that I know of. As long as a kernel comply to [the message spec](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/development/messaging.html) (and nice [blog post about messaging protocol from the guy who wrote IHaskell](http://andrew.gibiansky.com/blog/ipython/ipython-kernels/)) it is transparent for the frontend that just send strings/ receive results.

If you want a more stand-alone version you can look at Min's [single cell](https://github.com/minrk/singlecell) demo. But basically you should be able to embed IPython's `kernel.js` in a page, and just use `IPython.kernel.execute(code, callbacks)`.

The exact way of how this work in the kernel differs from language to language. Python can natively do so as you can eval a buch of code in a specific namespace, for other languages I can't tell you exactly.

Instead of reinventing, I think re-using IPython's message spec and reusable component would make sens[1].

Also I've heard from reliable source that IPython want the ability to start notebook with languages in different languages, and that they also want some closer than a REPL (like QtConsole) in the browser[2].

[1] I'm biased, I'm an IPython dev.

[2] That something we often talk about, but we have some Python-ism we want to get rid of first.