# Node.js streaming python autocomplete entries

Tags: python, node.js, stream, socket.io, ipython

I am making a web app that has a command line interface to IPython and I would like to add autocompletion. So far the reading and writing of stdout/stdin is working okay and I can transmit commands, but I am stuck implementing the autocomplete feature. I tried sending in `\t` through stdin, but that isn't the way to go. Is there a way to do this?

Here is my basic server logic:

```
var python = spawn('ipython', ['-i']);
s.on('run', function (input) {
  python.stdin.write(input.command + '\n');
});
python.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  var output = '' + data;
  s.emit('response', {
    output: output
  });
});
python.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  var output = '' + data;
  s.emit('response', {
    error: output
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why so much hate for uppercase I? It's IPython (as not build by Apple), but it's OK.

That being said, why using the hard path of reinventing the wheel an
not read other [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19610542/repl-in-webpage-best-way-to-go-about-it) about the same subject?

I guess yours is slightly different in that you have js on server side so you can require
ZMQ on server side and comply to [the message spec](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/development/messaging.html) (and nice [blog post about messaging protocol from the guy who wrote IHaskell](http://andrew.gibiansky.com/blog/ipython/ipython-kernels/)). With that it will be lot less brittle than parsing stdout, have more feature (send images). Also you will have other languages for free, and if you make a bridge to websockets, I guess you can reuse `kernel.js`.

Dumb question but Have you seen IPython notebook? Look like there would be a lot you can reuse from that.